# Sum of $n^{-\lambda}$ over an infinite subset of positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $A$ be an arbitrary infinite subset of positive integers such that for some $\lambda>0$, we have
$$\sum_{n\in A}\frac{1}{n^\lambda}=\infty.$$

I wonder if the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\sum_{\frac{k}{2}<n\le k,n\in A}1 \right)}{k^{\lambda+1}}=\infty$$

as well.

---

The key difficulty of proof is that we don't know the behavior of

$$\frac{\sum_{\frac{k}{2}<n\le k,n\in A}1}{k}$$

while I also had a hard time constructing a counterexample showing $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\sum_{\frac{k}{2}<n\le k,n\in A}1 \right)}{k^{\lambda+1}}<\infty$.

Comment: If you define $f(k)=\left|A\cap (k/2,k]\right|$ then you need, for a counterexample, that for any $c>0,$ you’d need the set $A_c=\{k\mid f(k)<ck\}$ to have at least lower density zero, which is to say $$\liminf_{m\to\infty}\frac{\left|A_c\cap[1,m]\right|}{\left|A\cap[1,m]\right|}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true; $S:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-\lambda-1}\sum_{n\in A,k/2<n\leqslant k}1$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n\in A}n^{-\lambda}$ does.

Since $k/2<n\leqslant k\iff n\leqslant k<2n$, we have $S=\sum_{n\in A}s_n$ where $s_n=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}k^{-\lambda-1}$, and $$n^\lambda s_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\left(\frac kn\right)^{-\lambda-1}\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_1^2 x^{-\lambda-1}\,dx\color{gray}{=\frac{1-2^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}},$$ so that the claim follows by the comparison test.